# leaps from Splus to R - unused argument really.big issue

Tags: r, matrix, s-plus

I have a code in Splus, but have to convert it into R, which is not a big thing. However I am very new to both softwares. This is the code I am struggling with:

```
a <- leaps(x, y, wt = wt, method = "adjr2", nbest=nbest, 
 names = dimnames(x)[[2]], int=F)
```

x is a matrix of independent variables where first length(keep1) columns correspond to variables that are always kept in BMA (Bayesian Model Averaging -- this isn't important. Essentially, x is a matrix), and y is a matrix too.

When I selected my data and ran the function this was part of, I got the following error:

> Error in leaps.exhaustive(a) :    Exhaustive search will be S L O W,
>   must specify really.big=T

So, I changed the initial command to:

```
 a <- leaps(x, y, wt = wt, method = "adjr2", nbest=nbest, 
 names = dimnames(x)[[2]], int=F, really.big=T)
```

When I ran the function again, I got this error:

> Error in leaps(x, y, wt = wt, method = "adjr2", nbest = nbest, names =
>   dimnames(x)[[2]],  :    unused argument (really.big = T)

The function is being called in this way:

```
out.dkt<-dkt.bma(bigx, bigy, bigz.sys, Tper=3,  hendog, name.x, name.z, 
emethod="LS", info.crit="BIC", h, keep1,  leaps.genR2="F",
nbest=1000, hier=1, q=0.50, OW=0,OR=1000,
filo="U:\\Programanddatafiles\\dkt-jae-ls-bic-hier1-sys-nokeep-nbest-check.txt")
```

So When I am using really.big, R tells me that it is an unused argument, but tells me to use it when I don't. What is going on here? Any help appreciated!

Comment: You have asked a half-dozen question with what seems to be near-identical questions. Do you really think that is the best way?

Comment: Trying different things but aren't working out. They're near identical questions because I'm working on the same code, but the issues are different. Trying to be as specific as possible.

Comment: What package is `leaps` from?  Have you tried `traceback` ? Just because some function wants `really.big` set doesn't mean it's in the top-level function you call.

Comment: Figured it out - was a problem with the way leaps itself was being run. It didn't have a provision to run really.big even though it recognized it.

Comment: You should post your solution, with details (i.e. how to deal or not deal with `really.big`) for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Add T <- 60 before this

a <- leaps(x, y, wt = wt, method = "adjr2", nbest=nbest,
names = dimnames(x)[[2]], int=F, really.big=T)